# Why has Google increased radius of UI elements?

Tags: buttons, google

It has been like a month I have noticed Google is testing UI elements such as inputs and buttons that are curvier. As you see in the screenshot, theinput has much more radius than the previous one.

[image]

Is it just a trend or there are some well thought reason behind it?

Comment: Surely we can point to things Don Norman's design principals (affordance in particular) to explain the design changes. Many UIs including Googles have been flat even with the paper paradigm, this leads to Gestalt issues where the boundaries are not clear and the calls to action have a low comparative hierarchy compared to each other and other elements on the page.

Comment: Short of testing any of this (like most questions on this channel) everything is an opinion. Some can point to reasonable resources but ultimately we can't read the designers thoughts. The Google Chrome Blog posted by @maxathousand is the best insight we'll probably get, the rest is speculation. Unless of course, Alex Ainslie decides to show up and get involved.

Comment: I'm confused. This question is not based on opinion at all. "Why did Google redesign Chrome in this way?" is *directly answered by Chrome's lead designer*. There is no ambiguity here, no inferences, and no guessing. The close reason states that "this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." I vote to reopen.

Comment: @maxathousand seriously, this is going out of hand. A few months ago a question was closed as primarily based even though the answer came from me, who actually worked on the project. And there are many examples of "primarily opinion based" questions that are well and extensively documented. At some point I just gave up and don't fight it anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [an interview about this redesign](https://www.blog.google/products/chrome/redesigning-chrome-interview-chromes-lead-designer/) published on the Google Chrome Blog.

Alex Ainslie, Chrome's lead designer states:

> We’re introducing a major refresh on Chrome across all platforms, which **aligns with Google’s new Material Theme**. This update involved changing our approaches to shape, color, iconography, and typography. And why right now? You only turn 10 once, so we thought it would be the ideal moment.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. *"Is it just a trend or there are some well thought reason behind it?"* If there's anything in the interview addressing that, suggest quoting it in the answer. Or if there's some explanation of curvier aspects to the Material theme. But this currently just reads as "They redesigned stuff" which...we kinda knew. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see what you’re saying, but I’d say that the “well thought reason behind it” is to bring it in line with their Material Theme, as the lead designer mentions in the article. Now, explaining why their Material Theme looks the way it does is a different, much larger question :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder saying "aligns with Material Theme" is their primary motivation, implies it's mostly following a trend, without specific UX considerations, except *maybe* consistency across platforms (but not with other apps on Windows!).

Comment: @dbkk It does not imply it’s a trend, it implies that they’ve established guidelines for their products, and they’re bringing their apps in line. Again, how they developed Material Theme is a separate question.